# How do you deploy to JBoss EAP sitting within a running docker container using the jboss-as-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jboss, docker

I have adopted a number of maven projects, and would like to move from deploying them to a VM housing JBoss and a VM housing the Database, to a docker setup similar to [this](http://blog.arungupta.me/wildfly-javaee7-mysql-link-two-docker-container-techtip65/)

However rather than copying the war across in the Dockerfile, we require to move it across to the running container using the jboss-as-maven-plugin as part of the maven lifecycle.

All things like open ports are sorted, as I'm able to access the database from the host.

At the moment I receive an error when trying to deploy the war.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (pre-integration-test) on project chess: Could not execute goal deploy on /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Chess_Docker/workspace/target/Chess.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:35800. The connection failed: XNIO000812: Connection closed unexpectedly
```

Could anyone shed any light on what the problem is?

Many Thanks,
Stuart

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with the similar problem only with the jboss-cli.
The problem was the different version of the used jboss-cli used for deploy and the target server's version.

Using the same version as the target server would solve the problem.